# Offset commits are getting failed in kafka 0.10.2.2

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using kafka-client version 0.10.2.2 and there are total 10 kafka consumer threads. During rebalancing 4/10 joined the group successfully and on rest 6 threads i am getting the following logs:

- Marking the coordinator dead for group[xyz].
- Discovered coordinator for group[xyz].
  These 6 threads never joined the group and they were still processing the messages but offset commit for them are getting fail.
  Has anyone also faced similar problem?

Comment: how many partitions does your kafka topic have? What do you mean with "they were still processing the messages but offset commit for them are getting fail"? Can you share the error message?

Comment: Our topic have 10 partitions. We were just getting logs such as "marking the coordinator dead" and "discovered coordinator for group" and didn't got any error messages. "They were still processing the messages but offset commit for them are getting fail" this mean that the threads which didn't joined the group were also fetching the messages from kafka server.